# How to save a textbox query result to a database after editing it? - MS Access

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access, textbox

Table of Documents:

```
Company    Document       Status        Notes:
A            1            Submission    Submitted on 12-12-12
A            1            Review        Reviewed on 12-12-13
A            1            Adopted       Adopted on 12-12-14
A            2            Submission    Submitted on 01-01-01
A            2            Review        Reviewed on 01-01-02
A            2            Adopted       Adopted on 01-01-03
```

I have two combo boxes on a form; first combo box allows me to select the document and is linked up to the first query: e.g. Selecting '1' would return:

```
Company    Document       Status        Notes:
A            1            Submission    Submitted on 12-12-12
A            1            Review        Reviewed on 12-12-13
A            1            Adopted       Adopted on 12-12-14
```

The second combo box then allows me to select its' status and is linked up to the second query; the second query is used to filter the results from the first query: e.g. Selecting 'Adopted' would return:

```
Company    Document       Status        Notes:
A            1            Adopted       Adopted on 12-12-14
```

Lastly, I have a text box that displays the 'Notes' field based on your selection from both of the combo boxes. E.g. Selecting '1', and then 'Adopted' would display this in the text box:

```
'Adopted on 12-12-14'
```

I can edit the text (Note) that appears in the text box, but I want to assign a function to a button, that when clicked; will replace the 'Notes' field in the database with the text that is currently in the text box.

I've been searching for a while and can't seem to get anything working; I know the code will go in the click_event properties of the button; but I'm not sure what code to use exactly. In it's most standard form, I want this to happen when the button is clicked:

```
UPDATE Document(Table) SET Notes(Field)=textboxname.value
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You've wired up 2 comboboxes at this point, but you're not sure how to fire off a click event for a button to grab a text box value and run a SQL statement to update a record given that value. It's hard to gauge where your lack of clarity lies here. Can you try to elaborate on which point of the process you're unsure about? We would be glad to help you.

Comment: You seem to be lacking a primary key in your `Documents` table (or have omitted it). Include this PK in the second query, then you have your WHERE clause for the UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Andre I'm wondering if the first 3 columns are a composite key. It looks like for a company and a document, there can only be 1 Status.

Comment: Or you could just have the 'Notes' textbox bound to your recordset, then it will update automatically when you move to another record. If worried about a mistake being made by the user, you could have a 'confirm' popup message that would allow for saving changes or cancelling.

Comment: @MarkC. I literally just need the code that would go in a button_click event that takes the value of the textbox, and replaces the 'Notes' field in the documents table with the value in the text box. I can't do it because I'm not familiar with VB/SQL code and don't know the appropriate format/function names etc. It's taken me quite a long time to get where I'm at now

Comment: @MarkC. Each company will have multiple documents. There are 3 statuses for each document. I need to be able to see a note for each status that the document was at; hence why the same document is listed 3 times, each time with a different status and a different note.. I hope that makes any sense

Comment: @Alex it does. I'm well aware of everything that's going on here. I don't have Access anymore since I switched companies, but basically you can add a button, right click on the button and go to properties, then events, on click, then you have a few options. Run a query, or do stuff in VBA that will do whatever you want. If you just go the query route, you just put the query name in the click event and use the fields on your form in the WHERE clause. Probably doesn't help, but that's the best I could do right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will allow you to enter text, then will execute the sql command to update notes in a record.

1. You will need to place this code inside your button click.
2. You need to change the names of the comboBoxes in the sql to use the names you have.
3. I assume there is not a unique key to use instead of 'document' and 'status'?
4. I certainly hope the document numbers never repeat across companies, else you will update multiple rows!

   ```
   Private Sub cmdAddNote_Click()
   Dim strNote As String
   Dim strSQL  As String
   Dim dbs     As DAO.Database

   strNote = InputBox("Enter notes below, then click OK:", "Add Notes")
   If strNote = "" Then
       ' Cancel
   Else

       strSQL = "UPDATE [Documents] SET [Documents].Notes = '" & strNote & "' " & _
                "WHERE ((([Documents].[Document])= '" & cbo1 & "') AND (([Documents].[Status])='" & cbo2 & "'));"
       Set dbs = CurrentDb
       dbs.Execute strSQL
       dbs.Close
       Set dbs = Nothing
   End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I failed to mention I have a third combo box which displays the company names - Because of the double Query setup and specific search parameters; I'm able to display 1 **SINGLE** result; meaning even if multiple companies have the same document names; I'll be able to specify exactly which document it is, for which company. So your code **WILL** work even if the document numbers/names are the same across multiple companies. You've essentially hit two birds with one stone, well done.